# How do I split a string, breaking at a symbol ':'?

Tags: javascript, split

I have this string

```
24.733835, 121.34365500000001:AP-54184
```

i want to spilt the string by ':' , but why can't spilt the string

```
    var newarray= '24.733835, 121.34365500000001:AP-54184'.spilt(/:/);
    document.write(newarray[0]+","+newarray[1]+"<br>");
```

Is there anything wrong with my code ?

Comment: Check the console and tell us what the error is. Meanwhile people are trying to spam their way for rep...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no function `spilt()` unless it's part of the `Milk` class. You want `split(':')`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code, it should be `.split()`, not `.spilt()`...